# What does this "note: see declaration of '_PyInitError'" error mean when trying to package a C module using 'distutil'?

Tags: python, sha256, distutils

Following my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374359/why-is-hashlib-so-faster-than-other-codes-for-sha256-and-how-can-i-get-my-code-c), I would like to import [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/sha256module.c) C/C++ implementation of `sha256` into my python script `(Python 3.7.0)` and run some performance tests.

From the official documentation it seems that one way of doing this is to use `distutil` built-in module of python to package this as a new module and then install it so that it becomes importable to any script.

The first step I took was to download the `sha256module.c` code and save it into my current directory. In the same directory, I then created a `setup.py` with the following content that python's documentation recommends [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/examples.html).

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
setup(name='sha256_test1',
      version='1.0',
      description = 'This is a test sha256 function',
      ext_modules=[Extension('sha256', sources = ['sha256module.c'])],
      )
```

After creating the setup file, from command prompt and in the same directory as the setup I run `python setup.py build`. In the first place, I received "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error and based on the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534000/windows-10-and-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) question I installed visual studio 2017 community version on my Win10 x64 operating system. The error is gone. But I received errors indicating lack of some other files that seemed necessary for packaging. They are listed as:

```
hashlib.h
coreconfig.h
pystrhex.h
python.h
structmember.h
tracemalloc.h
clinic/sha256module.c.h
```

I added them to the current directory and when I run `python setup.py build` again I get another error saying "note: see declaration of '_PyInitError" which I assumed might be from the lack of `__init__.py` so I created an empty one but it didn't work.

I am not sure if I am doing this all the way right. What do you think about this procedure?! Am I on the correct direction?! If yes please tell me how to tackle the error and if no please indicate why and where I am doing wrong.